# Using JS, is it possible to return a list of all CSS stylesheets included in a page, when it loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery or plain JavaScript, can I return a list of every stylesheet included in a page when it initially loads?

All I want to do is print out a list of stylesheet names into the console, no additional info on the stylesheets is required.

Comment: `querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]')`

Comment: I wonder why you added a bounty _Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources._, what are your intents if i may ask?

Comment: are you looking for the names of the stylesheet files or is it for their individual style rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am correct, by *Names* you mean the file name of each stylesheet.

Consider this example:

```
jQuery("link[href*='.css']").each(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).attr('href').split('/').pop());
});
```

Here I am using this `link[href*='.css']` selector to select all (include the inactive) stylesheets.

Answer (score 4):

if using jQuery:

```
console.log($('link[rel=stylesheet]'));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr("href"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzfhjg16/

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code collects all `link`s with the `rel` attribute on `stylesheet`, then iterates over them and logs their attribute `href`. You can use the line in the loop to display the stylesheet names anywhere you want to.

```
$("head link[rel='stylesheet']").each(function (){
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/wapoxoluji/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var styles = document.styleSheets;
$(styles).each(function(index,value){
    console.log(value.href==null ? null : value.href.split('/').pop())
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets

Comment: Some reason for downvoting this? Not jQueryish enough perhaps?